# Persisting XML parsed object

Tags: java, android

I am using an xml parser to parse the login response from a request to a server. The xml content returns me `sensitive data` that uniquely identifies a client so i can fetch more details about the client in other part of my app later on.

In iOS, i would just create an object from the parsed values to hold the `clientAuthenticationDetails` and access it from anywhere else in the app using the `appDelegate` instance.

Is there a way for me to do the same in Android? I have read up on `SharedPreferences` but i am not sure if that is how others implement this sort of functionality or how `secure` it is since i do have sensitive client data in the response.

Comment: How to help you without the code?

Comment: Well my question is more about how to implement a concept. Essentially, how can i persist an object constructed from an xml parser across the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy option is to use Shared Preferences and write up some sort of method that will encrypt/decrypt the values in the preferences. Usually something like a DES encoder/decoder. you can find samples of using cypher anywhere.

The Harder option which usually doesn't make sense to implement is to store the account and credentials in the android `AccountManager`. I suggest going with the Shared Preferences option. Its enough in my opinion.